# Why am I getting the current month and year as the default value for a DateTime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm looking through the codebase of a project I'm working on, and I have a method in the controller that sets up the view by populating a list with months and years, and then passing it to the view

```
ViewBag.ListOfYears = new SelectList(years, person.Date_of_Graduation.GetValueOrDefault().Year.ToString("00"));

ViewBag.ListOfMonths = new SelectList(months, person.Date_of_Graduation.GetValueOrDefault().Month.ToString("00"));
```

But when I look at the dropdown list on the actual page, it has 06 as the month selected by default and 2015 as the year by default. I thought that the default value of DateTime Ojects was 1 as the month and 0001 as the year. Can somebody explain to me why the current month and year are the default in the dropbox?

Comment: You haven't told us what the value of `person.Date_of_Graduation.GetValueOrDefault()` is when you are encountering this problem. Is it actually `default(DateTime)` or is it a date in this month? Also what is the type of `Date_of_Graduation`? Is it definitely a `DateTime?` rather than a custom type of some sort? You are right though about the default of DateTime (though I'm assuming you'd already confirmed that via test or google and that your comment was rhetorical).

Comment: @Chris Um, Date_of_Graduation is of type Nullable<System.DateTime> and the value of person.Date_of_Graduation.GetValueOrDefault() is 6/1/2015 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Then the problem is almost certainly that `Date_of_Graduation` is not null. Check if `Date_of_Graduation.HasValue` is true (I'd expect it is). Likewise `Date_of_Graduation.Value`is likely to be that date. So you are looking in the wrong place for your bug. Your bug is actually that the date is being set when you are not expecting it to be, not that the default is not what you expect.

Comment: Yeah, it says Date_of_Graduation.HasValue is true. How can the date have been set before I expected it to? Where should I start looking to see if it was somehow set already? @Chris

Comment: Sadly that is a little outside of the scope of this question since I have no idea what your code does, where it saves things, etc. My first check would be create a new person and check the database (or wherever you are persisting it) to see if it is there on start. If it is that should narrow it down. If not then it's just a case of looking in code for all the places you set that value and try to work out if it is being set there (breakpoints on uses of the property setter are helpful). Or if you have a repository type pattern breakpoints on all saves of the object.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I actually found that when the Person object gets created it sets the graduation date to now for some reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `person.Date_of_Graduation` has a value other than null or there's a value in `ModelState` for whatever property you're binding this select list to. For example, given:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GraduationYear, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListOfYears)
```

Then if a value is set for any of `ViewBag.GraduationYear`, `ViewData["GraduationYear"]`, `Request["GraduationYear"]`, or `Model.GraduationYear` (where `Model` is your view's model instance), then that value will be set as the selected value in the dropdown.